# Getting depth of recursive function React.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I am trying to solve a JavaScript/React.js exercice to practice recursive functions in which you have an input object (that can have multiple depth levels) and you want to output a "tree" with the object content like below:

```
//Input object
const input = {
  key1: {
    key11: 'v11',
  },    
  key2: {
    key21: {
      key211: 'v211',
    },
  },
  key3: 'v3',
}

/* Desired output:
key1:
--key11: v11
key2:
--key21:
----key211: v211
key3: v3
*/
```

I have managed to develop the App.jsx component that makes the recursive calls:

```
class App extends React.Component {  
    renderObject(input, level=0){
    return (Object.entries(input).map((item, index) => {
      if(typeof item[1] === "string"){
        let object = <div key={`${item[0]}-level-${level}`}><span>{"--".repeat(level)}</span>{item[0]}: {item[1]}</div>;
        level = 0;
        return object;
      } else {
        let object = <div key={`${item[0]}-level-${level}`}><span>{"--".repeat(level)}</span>{item[0]}: { this.renderObject(item[1], ++level)}</div>
        return (object)
      }
    }))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            {this.renderObject(input)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

The problem I am facing is that the `level` I have implemented is not showing the real depth, because it also increments in each iteration in the first level (when it should remain 0).

```
/* Obtained output: 
key1:
--key11: v11
--key2:
----key21:
------key211: v211
----key3: v3
*/
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Don't use `++level` and `level = 0`. The recursive call should be `level + 1` and that's it. If you use `++level` and `level = 0`, then it changes the current level for siblings when those should all be the same value. Only child calls should have a different value, specifically `level + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer, the problem is related to mutating the value of `level` with `++level` and `level = 0` in the body of the recursive function. Looking at the printed result, the goal is for each level to have the same indentation, so with `++level`, future siblings in the loop at the same level will be indented at increasing distances. `level = 0` might have been an attempt at rectifiying this problem, but it doesn't work because level shouldn't be 0 once the recursion starts.

The solution is to treat `level` as effectively immutable during the body of the function, then use `level + 1` as the parameter to set up the child recursive calls to the appropriate level.

Here's the code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  renderObject(o, level = 0) {
    return Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => (
      <div key={[k, v, level].join("-")}>
        <span>{"--".repeat(level)}</span>
        {k}:{" "}
        {typeof v === "object"
          ? this.renderObject(v, level + 1)
          : v}
      </div>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderObject(this.props.tree)}</div>;
  }
}

const tree = {
  key1: {
    key11: "v11",
  },
  key2: {
    key21: {
      key211: "v211",
    },
  },
  key3: "v3",
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App tree={tree} />);
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `level + 1` instead of `++level`